# Why can't I acces my NAS drive with rclone?

Tags: command-line, nas, network-drive, rclone

I am trying to access my NAS drive with rclone:

```
rclone check C:\Some_local_folder "N:\"
```

where `N:\` is my NAS drive. However, I can't seem to access my NAS in this way:

```
2020-06-18 20:24:25 ERROR : file.jpg: File not in Local file system at //?/N:/
```

However, in the same command line window, I can access my NAS with `ls N:\` for example. How can I access my NAS with rclone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running "rclone check". That will not make chances to local or remote. It will only check if local and remote are the same. Looks like a file that is present on local is not found at remote.

So you **are** accessing your NAS.

The notation you are seeing is a consequence of the UNC expansion:

Long paths on Windows
Rclone handles long paths automatically, by converting all paths to long UNC paths which allows paths up to 32,767 characters.

This is why you will see that your paths, for instance c:\files is converted to the UNC path \?\c:\files in the output, and \server\share is converted to \?\UNC\server\share. (https://rclone.org/local/#long-paths-on-windows)